# Transfer Learning for Regression in Matlab

Tags: matlab, regression, transfer-learning

I am trying to implement a model that takes an image as the input and gives a vector of 26 numbers. I am using VGG-16 at this time through the following Matlab code:

```
analyzeNetwork(net);
NUM_OUTPUT = 26;
layers = net.Layers;
%output = fullyConnectedLayer(NUM_OUTPUT, ...
%                             'Name','output_layer', ...
%                             'WeightLearnRateFactor',10, ...
%                             'BiasLearnRateFactor',10);
layers = [
    layers(1:38)
    fullyConnectedLayer(NUM_OUTPUT)
    regressionLayer];

%layers(1:67) = freezeWeights(layers(1:67));
miniBatchSize  = 5;
validationFrequency = floor(numel(YTrain)/miniBatchSize);
options = trainingOptions('sgdm',...
    'InitialLearnRate',0.001, ...
    'ValidationData',{XValidation,YValidation},...
    'Plots','training-progress',...
    'Verbose',false);

net = trainNetwork(XTrain,YTrain,layers,options);
YPred = predict(net,XValidation);
predictionError = YValidation - YPred;
thr = 10;
numCorrect = sum(abs(predictionError) < thr);
numImagesValidation = numel(YValidation);

accuracy = numCorrect/numImagesValidation;
rmse = sqrt(mean(predictionError.^2));
```

The shape of XTrain and YTrain are as follows: 
**XTrain:** 224 224 3 140 
**YTrain:** 26 140

By running the code above (it is a part of the code not the whole of it) I get the following error:

**Error using trainNetwork (line 170)
Number of observations in X and Y disagree.**

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me to figure out what is the problem because as far as I know the number of samples in both are equal and there is no necessity for the rest of the dimensions to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Transpose YTrain to be 140x26.

Name your new layers, and make them `layerGraph`

Regression can easly go unstable so decrease learning rate or increase batch size if you get some nans.

```
net = vgg16 ; % analyzeNetwork(net);
LAYERS_FREEZE_UNTIL=35;
LAYERS_COPY_UNTIL=38;


NUM_TRAIN_SAMPLES = size(YTrain,1);
NUM_OUTPUT = size(YTrain,2);


my_layers =layerGraph([
    freezeWeights(net.Layers(1:LAYERS_FREEZE_UNTIL))
    net.Layers(LAYERS_FREEZE_UNTIL+1:LAYERS_COPY_UNTIL)
    fullyConnectedLayer(NUM_OUTPUT*2,'Name','my_fc1')
    fullyConnectedLayer(NUM_OUTPUT,'Name','my_fc2')
    regressionLayer('Name','my_regr')
    ]);
% figure; plot(my_layers), ylim([0.5,6.5])
% analyzeNetwork(my_layers);

MINI_BATCH_SIZE = 16;

options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'MiniBatchSize',MINI_BATCH_SIZE, ...
    'MaxEpochs',20, ...
    'InitialLearnRate',1e-4, ...
    'Shuffle','every-epoch', ...
    'ValidationData',{XValidation,YValidation}, ...
    'ValidationFrequency',floor(NUM_TRAIN_SAMPLES/MINI_BATCH_SIZE), ...
    'Verbose',true, ...
    'Plots','training-progress');

my_net = trainNetwork(XTrain,YTrain,my_layers,options);
```